# Twitter User Hash for Sorcery Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, twitter-oauth

I'm using the Sorcery gem and their external module to authenticate with Twitter. I've got the authentication working, but I want to store the user's Twitter profile image URL in my database after a successful log in. Sorcery seems to have a configuration option that's meant to do exactly what I want:

```
config.twitter.user_info_mapping = {:nickname => "screen_name"}
```

Maybe I've missed something in the Sorcery documentation, but I can't find any information about what "keys" are available. I tried this to no avail:

```
config.twitter.user_info_mapping = {:nickname => "screen_name", :avatar_url => "profile_image_url"}
```

Has anyone found documentation about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is just what you get from twitter in json format.
Here is a twitter documentation about it https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/account/verify_credentials

```
config.twitter.user_info_mapping = {:username => "screen_name", 
                                    :realname => "name", 
                                    :location => "place", 
                                    :web => "url",
                                    :bio => "description"}
```